# Service to Search RSS Feeds like Pulse App

Tags: rss, feed

I want to known what is the search engine who use Linkedin Pulse (app).  I'm developing a Rss Reader and I'm interested to use a service to provide rss feeds by keywords.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they use any 3rd party tool... they just aggregated a lot of data over the years and have tons of urls.

Comment: I don't think. Could be.  There are some search engines, like http://www.rssmicro.com/ or maybe http://www.rsssearchhub.com/ or the best http://ctrlq.org/rss/ but I can't find a way to use those results as pure data.